# Struct in MVC4 Web API causes route to break

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a simple controller with a parameter-less Get and a Get that takes in an id.

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    public string Get(Identity id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

Identity is a custom struct that, simplified, looks like this:

```
public struct Identity
{
    // ....
    public Identity(Guid value)
    {
        internalValue = value;
    }
}
```

However, I receive an error stating that multiple actions were found that match the request if I attempt to navigate to either endpoint. The BooksController works just fine if the Get for a single resource takes in a Guid rather than my Identity struct.

My custom model binder and wire-up:

```
public class IdentityModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        Identity identity = new Identity(Guid.Parse(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).AttemptedValue));
        bindingContext.Model = identity;
        return true;
    }
}

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.BindParameter(typeof(Identity), new IdentityModelBinder());
```

Note, the above binds fine if any parameters are added to the parameter-less Get. That is, if I change my BooksController to:

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get(int page, string searchTerm)
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    public string Get(Identity id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

My route configuration is just the out of the box example:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Then I can correctly navigate to both endpoints. How do I go about setting up my BooksController to allow both the parameter-less Get and a Get that takes in my custom Identity?

Comment: can you show how your routes are configured

Comment: @dakait I've added the route configuration. It's just the out of the box route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the source of my troubles and I don't see a way around it.

Within the Web API ApiControllerActionSelector, specifically in the ActionCacheSelectorItem.ctor, the logic for resolving action parameters is:

```
_actionParameterNames.Add(
       actionDescriptor,
       actionBinding.ParameterBindings
                    .Where(binding => !binding.Descriptor.IsOptional && TypeHelper.IsSimpleUnderlyingType(binding.Descriptor.ParameterType) && binding.WillReadUri())
                    .Select(binding => binding.Descriptor.Prefix ?? binding.Descriptor.ParameterName).ToArray());
```

Unfortunately, this means that only simple types (primitive, datetime, guid, etc) will be included in the parameter list. I can get my struct to show up in the parameter list if I extend the filter logic above to also consider if the parameter can be converted from a string like so:

```
_actionParameterNames.Add(
       actionDescriptor,
       actionBinding.ParameterBindings
                    .Where(binding => !binding.Descriptor.IsOptional && 
                          (TypeHelper.IsSimpleUnderlyingType(binding.Descriptor.ParameterType) ||
                          TypeHelper.HasStringConverter(binding.Descriptor.ParameterType)) && 
                          binding.WillReadUri())
                    .Select(binding => binding.Descriptor.Prefix ?? binding.Descriptor.ParameterName).ToArray());
```

I am hoping I'm wrong. Will come back and mark this as the answer after the cooldown period if it turns out I'm stuck.